# Out of ideas: transformation of continuous variables to obtain normality of residuals seemingly impossible

Tags: multiple-regression, data-transformation, transform

I've been browsing stackexchange for days to come up with decent solutions, but to no avail so far. Some threads seem to apply and offer solutions (e.g. [How to transform negative data to be homoscedastic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94628/how-to-transform-negative-data-to-be-homoscedastic/94652#94652?newreg=42ad686b9501429aa45e1d3f3b76e58c); [How should I transform non-negative data including zeros?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/how-should-i-transform-non-negative-data-including-zeros); [When to transform predictor variables when doing multiple regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18320/when-to-transform-predictor-variables-when-doing-multiple-regression); [When conducting multiple regression, when should you center your predictor variables & when should you standardize them?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/when-conducting-multiple-regression-when-should-you-center-your-predictor-varia); [Variables are often adjusted (e.g. standardised) before making a model - when is this a good idea, and when is it a bad one?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19216/variables-are-often-adjusted-e-g-standardised-before-making-a-model-when-is); [Transforming extremely skewed distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88218/transforming-extremely-skewed-distributions); [R: test normality of residuals of linear model - which residuals to use](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118214/r-test-normality-of-residuals-of-linear-model-which-residuals-to-use)), but the nature of my data always puts spikes in the wheels.

I'm performing multiple regression on a set of categorical and continuous variables in order to determine which variables can explain variation in the dependent variable. One of the main challenges in the first phase of model building is to transform the continuous explanatory variables in order to achieve linear relations with the dependent variable, after all (as far as I understand) that's necessary for the model assumptions to be met. I won't even involve the categorical variables for now.

1. My dependent variable expresses the difference between empirically measured groundwater table (GWT) depths and modeled GWT depths. The difference can be either positive or negative and is not normally distributed (i.e. too heavy-tailed, I think). Not that it should be normally distributed, but it entails both positive and negative values (see infra).

[image: histogram of response variable]

2. All independent variables are exclusively positive, but very positively skewed. Two of the independent variables correlate severely, as they express the same factor (reduction in GWT depth, in the same unit as the dependent variable: cm) measured in winter and in summer. I will have to remove one from the final model eventually as in multiple regression correlating explanatory variables should be avoided. The third explanatory variable is measured in a different scale and represents something entirely else (distance to streams, in meters).

[image: positive skew in all explanatory continuous variables]

3. Because of the different scales of the three explanatory variables, I'm inclined to standardize, but that causes the explanatory variables to have positive and negative values, like the dependent variable, and that causes problems later on (with the transformations).
4. I generally try to counter the presence of positive and negative values by applying a min-max normalization to the explanatory variables (standardized or not standardized, I tried both), normalizing the data to the interval [1-2]. I deliberately do not normalize to the interval [0-1], after all I want to be taking logarithms afterwards (see infra).
   This is my code:

   ```
   zDstnc2S = (Dstnc2S-mean(Dstnc2S))/sd(Dstnc2S)
   minmax_12<- function(x) (x-min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)) * (2-1)+1
   zDstnc2S_MM<-minmax_12(zDstnc2S)
   c2<-lm(GHGVcmomv~log(zDstnc2S_MM))
   shapiro.test(c2$residuals)
   ```
5. Positively skewed data invites the statistician to apply a log-transformation or a reciprocal transformation or a square root transformation on the data, so I've learned ([Transforming extremely skewed distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88218/transforming-extremely-skewed-distributions)). I've run the transformations on the raw variables and on the min-maxed standardized variables.
   **The transformations don't seem to have an effect. Is that maybe because my dependent variable is not normally distributed?** Am I checking up on the effect of the transformation the wrong way? For each explanatory variable I separately run

   ```
   a<-lm(y~log(xi))
   ```

   and then check using

   ```
   plot(a)
   ```

   and

   ```
   shapiro.test(a$residuals)
   ```

   The W-value does not change a lot.
6. I've turned to more 'deterministic' ways of figuring out what transformation to use. I've run ggplot2 qplots on every (xi,y) combination. I've ran GAM. I've interpreted the graphical output of these tools as polynomial functions, as linear functions, as exponentials (I'm not very good at the interpretation, you've got me there - also: I would post the GAM output here but I'm only allowed to post two images here). I've tried to relate y to the xi in all of the ways mentioned in the last line. Nothing seems to improve the normality of my residuals. I've tried Box-cox, but it won't work on a dependent variable that has both positive and negative values. I've tried to run Boxcox with the min-max transformed dependent variable. Nope. Nope. Nope.

My three best guesses for the root cause of my problems are: (1) you can't effectively transform your explanatory variables to achieve normality when your dependent variable isn't normally distributed. (2) I'm checking the effectiveness of my transformations the wrong way - e.g. shapiro.test(lm$residuals) (3) I have no idea what I'm doing at all.

In case I do have to transform my dependent variable, how can I do so without losing valuable information? Remember: it's positive and negative, so @Nick Cox's cube root thing will reduce valuable information, namely that most o the yi are very close to zero. Again: I'd post the image, but after cube rooting the thing it looks like a Gaussian curve with mean 0 but it has a dip near zero, creating twin peaks ;)

I'd expand more but this post is way too long already. I suppose the answer is very simple, and I'm too silly to see it. I'll elaborate gratefully if more information is needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need any of the variables to look normal?

Comment: Agree, I suspect there's a misunderstanding regarding a need for normality here.

Comment: As far as your point 2 is concerned have you thought of entering the two variables as their average and difference? That would give you two variables which might have scientific meaning (overall reduction, difference between seasons) and which would not be so highly correlated.

Comment: @Glen-b and Björn, thanks for the replies, they reveal something I forgot to mention in my post: (residual) model plots indicate problems when I make a 'naive' linear model:

        lm_naive<-lm(y~x1+x2+x3)
        par(mfrow=c(2,2))
        plot(lm_naive)

This gives following result: https://s31.postimg.org/t0ezjc21n/image.png 

I always thought that these figures indicate model assumption problems, and given the very disturbing qqnorm plots I figured the main reason was their high skewedness.

https://s32.postimg.org/cxyrk70gl/image.png

Comment: @mdewey, that sounds like an excellent plan. I basically was going to include the one that has the most 'effect' on y, if any, and then figure out why it has more effect.

Comment: I would look at the high leverage points first. Are they (a) measurement errors (b) really interesting rare events (c) something else. I would not be that bothered by the skew of the predictors, the model is the focus of interest.

Comment: @mdewey: thanks for your feedback. I've done the following: determine the five points with highest leverage using     hat<-hatvalues(lm_naive)     and     tail(sort(hat),5). Investigated these points and to select one of your answers above - it's b. They have extreme (maxed) values for a variable that represents GWT drops caused by exraction wells. These five points are located right next to extraction wells. That's rare, but not incorrect. Also, they have such high leverage, I presume, because they have maxed values on two of the three explanatory variables that I run the model for.

Comment: @mdewey: And they have maxed value for 2/3 explanatory variables because these two variables represent the same thing, only in summer and in winter. Maybe it's best to apply your first suggestion: "entering the two variables as their average and difference" and see how the model evolves?

Comment: The question I would ask is: if you had thought about it in advance would you have sampled places right next to the wells? If the answer is no then I would remove them from the model (but report them separately, obviously).

Comment: The answer is yes. Although I didn't sample, I just overlayed a map of modeled GWT drops over my points and extracted the values. 
If anything: these points are ever so important. The idea is that high values for this x should come with high values of y, as the GWT drop is presumed to be accounted for in the empirical data (as it is likely to represent the physical truth) and not in the modeled GWT data, so the difference between emprirical GWT data and modeled GWT values (difference = my actual y) should be extreme for these points. If not, then there might locally be other factors at play

Comment: Is it worth adding distance from an extraction well as a covariate?

Comment: Instead of GWTdrop caused by extraction wells or as an extra covariate. How might it help?

Comment: @mdewey Based on your comments it dawned to me that maybe what you're getting at is that my residual plot clouds aren't necessarily bad or indicating that transformations are needed, but that high leverage points and outliers are very much screwing up the interpretability of the plots. Can this be right?

Comment: I would say the plots are telling you something helpful about the dataset rather than your dataset is messing up the plots but I think that is just a matter of language.